# Why is my code not working and checking the input

Tags: python

**[trying to check for "50" and other strings to see if they follow the if statements that i used and for some reason they don't, can someone help ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmvoF.png)**

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The first elif block always returns `True`.
Use `in` instead:

```
elif answer in {"forty-two", "forty two"}:
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al) for good explanations

Comment: Thank you very much (:. im pretty new to coding soo i dont know what im doing half of the time.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome, everyone started at some point! :) I've voted to close the question as it is a duplicate of the post i linked.